# MUI ListItemText primary text overflow the ListItem's secondary action

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, word-wrap

I'm working with MUI (v5) List.

It's a simple list in my case, each item has some text on the left and a value on the right.

The problem is, when the list gets smaller horizontally (i.e. the user starts to shrink the window size), the "left" text (`<ListItemText primary={...}/>`) starts to "overflow" or cover the text on the right, like this:

[image]

To demonstrate it, I used the code from MUI docs:

```
import * as React from "react";
import List from "@mui/material/List";
import ListItem from "@mui/material/ListItem";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";

export default function GutterlessList() {
  return (
    <List sx={{ width: "100%", bgcolor: "background.paper" }}>
      {[1, 2, 3].map((value) => (
        <ListItem key={value} disableGutters secondaryAction={"some text"}>
          <ListItemText
            primary={`Loooooooooooong looooooooooooooooooooong text ${value}`}
          />
        </ListItem>
      ))}
    </List>
  );
}
```

Here it is on code sandbox: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-stallman-84jd55?file=/Demo.tsx).

In this example, the word wrapping of the text on the left kicks in pretty fast, so it's not that bad, but in my case, it takes a while of "shrinking the windows size" to split the text on the left.

Is there a way to make it work like: when the text on the left would "collide"/"overflow"/"cover" the text on the right, the word wrapping (even breaking words) kick right in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `primaryTypographyProps` available in `ListItemText` to give **right padding** to primary `Typography`. Whatever you pass in `primary` prop of ListItemText is the primary Typography.

Also, you need to give some styles to ListItemText itself. Here's the working code sample:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import List from "@mui/material/List";
import ListItem from "@mui/material/ListItem";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";

export default function GutterlessList() {
  return (
    <List sx={{ width: "100%", bgcolor: "background.paper" }}>
      {[1, 2, 3].map((value) => (
        <ListItem
          key={value}
          disableGutters
          secondaryAction={"some text"}
        >
          <ListItemText
            primaryTypographyProps={{
              paddingRight: 8
            }}
            style={{ maxWidth: "fit-content", wordBreak: "break-all" }}
            primary={`Loooooooooooong looooooooooooooooooooong text ${value}`}
          />
        </ListItem>
      ))}
    </List>
  );
}
```

Notice the maxWidth and wordBreak in ListItemText.

Here's the code sandbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-shape-n8y4dm?file=/Demo.tsx

You can tweak the **paddingRight** in **primaryTypographyProps** to control the distance (between primary and secondary text) at which the word break is triggered.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I actually went with `disableTypography` now, because I don't use it everywhere and it screws up the font and its size. So I had to move the padding to `style=` (I actually use `sx=`). But it works, no more overlapping!

Comment: Glad I was of some help!